# Does PyCharm need to use PythonLauncher? Alternatives?

Tags: pycharm

I've configure PyCharm to use a Python 3.7 interpreter, mac.  Each time I run my .py code, PyCharm spawns a new PythonLauncher session, and they accumulate.  Periodically I have to force-quit them - a pain.  Is there a better way?  Thx.

I've done the standard web and PyCharm doc searches but don't see this issue addressed.

Comment: In `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console`, is the box `Use existing console for Run with Python console` ticked in?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Apparently I needed also to check "Emulate terminal in output console", in the configuration file.  So, success!